# Can I play DS games from any region on the 3DS?

Tags: nintendo-ds, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, region-lock

I have a North American 3DS, and I really, really want to get a copy of the DS game [Freshly Picked: Tingle's Rosy Rupeeland](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Freshly-Picked-Tingles-Rupeeland-Nintendo/dp/B000T5W5KE/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1322350156&sr=8-1).

However, the only way to get it in North America is to import a European copy (if I want to play it in English, which I do).

I know that DS cartridges played in a DS aren't region-locked, but since I don't understand region locking (and I know that the 3DS are region-specific - you can't play a Japanese 3DS game on a North American 3DS for example), I am wondering if my plan is even feasible.

So, before I spend money on the game, is what I want to do even possible?

Comment: I think some work while others don't, for example most Nintendo developed US imports seem to work fine for me but my American copies of Chrono Trigger, Dragonball Origins and GTA all fail to start up.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, what you want to do is possible. While all 3DS software [is region-locked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27565/is-the-nintendo-3ds-region-locked), [Nintendo DS software is not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_lockout#Nintendo). Because that region-locking isn't encoded into the DS software, you can play software from all regions on your 3DS.

You can even check out this youtube video where someone demonstrates a DS games from North America, Japan, and Europe on their North American 3DS.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it the other way around. You cannot play N.A. games on a European 3ds but you can play European games on an N.A. 3ds.

Answer (score -10):

No you can not.  Whoever says you can is just telling you the wrong thing.

Comment: The other answer says you can, and provides video evidence. Can you provide video evidence (or at least any evidence of any sort) to support your claim?

Comment: @Absurd What you're saying, I dare say, is *absurd* ಠ_ರೃ

Comment: Actually, I have since gotten a DS game from the EU and played it on my NA 3DS and it works just fine. So, you, actually are wrong.

Comment: YES THIS IS GOOD IT DOSEN'T WORK ON MY 3DS