# Is there a way to remove the region lock on a 3DS and still connect to the nintendo store

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, hardware, region-lock

I have an old DS Lite, and I want to get the *Etrian Odyssey* series, but the 4th one only came out on 3DS, so I'm going to get a 3DS.

But since the 3DS is region locked I was thinking of getting all the games from the same region so that I can play them all of the 3DS.

However the copies of *Etrian Odyssey* 2 and 3 I've found on Ebay are in the US, so I am wondering, Is there any way I can remove the region locking on a 3DS while still having the other features of the 3DS, such as the Nintendo Store?

**NOTE:** the 3DS is an Australian brought one so it should be Australian

Comment: This seems to be on-topic as per the ff: [meta] posts: [What's the official stance on hacked/modded consoles?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/258/4797), [Should questions like “How can I install Firefox on the PS3?” be allowed?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3366/4797) and [How should we deal with direct questions on hardware modding?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3877/4797)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original *[Etrian Oddyssey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etrian_Odyssey)* games are DS titles, therefore they ***wont be restricted by 3DS region locking*** as established in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38686/can-i-play-ds-games-from-any-region-on-the-3ds/38687#38687).

This means it doesn't matter where you get *Etrian Oddyssey* 1, 2 & 3, they will play on any 3DS device in any region.

Just make sure to buy your 3DS & your copy of *[Etrian Oddessey 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etrian_Odyssey_4)* from the same region. As you've mentioned it's a 3DS-exclusive title, and will be subject to region-locking.

Comment: it was just for the Etrian Oddyssey games i wanted to remove any region locking so i could play them all on the same console but if the first 3 can't be played on a 3DS regardless of region then i don't need to worry about removing any region locking

Comment: @Memor DS games can be played on 3DS. I'm not sure why you think this answer says they can't be.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - I think that's a typo from Memor-X

Comment: @SevenSidedDie yeh it's a typo that I keep making/missing, I was meant to say "if the first 3 can be played on a 3DS"

Comment: That does make more sense. :)