# Is the 2DS region locked? Will I be able to play NA games on a Japanese System?

Tags: region-lock, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

If I purchase a 2DS from Japan, will I be able to play American games on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this site](http://en.rocketnews24.com/2013/10/15/hands-on-with-the-new-nintendo-2ds-plenty-of-bang-for-not-many-bucks/):

> Like the Nintendo 3DS before it, the new 2DS is region-locked, which, unfortunately, means that devices can only play games with the same region codes, and you can’t access online stores from different regions.

Since Japan is a whole different region than North America, you can't play North American games on it.

See [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/27566/163757) for more information on how Nintendo does region locking (its for the 3ds, but it should be identical for the 2ds).

Comment: Thank you so much for the information!  That is what I thought, but the info I saw online was not very clear.

Comment: This region locking is pretty terrible.  I wanted to try some Japan only games but I'm not about to buy a new system for one game...