# New Nintendo 2DS XL - Switzerland Region Lock

Tags: region-lock, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

Recently I bought the New Nintendo 2DS XL in Switzerland together with 2 games.

I just realized that the games are French/German edition.

Now, I have to go back to Italy, does this means that I can only play German/French games with this console?

The region lock is also for the Swiss version of the console?

Many many thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are currently three regions for the 3DS/2DS:

1. America
2. Japan
3. Europe/Australia

Because the countries you name are all in the same region (Europe), **you will have no problems**.

Source for this are these two answers: [1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/27566/80141), [2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/293435/80141)